# How to Get HttpErrorResponse Angular In Post Request to API

Tags: angular, api, rest, authentication, token

Sorry I'm New In Front End Developing

I already made a system login on angular but my system login doesn't return an error message if the token  failed to get or got HttpErrorResponse

I want to show the error message as wrong password / username to user

#### This is the response if no username and password in my API

[image: How to catch di response in my post method]

#### api.service.ts

`baseUrlAuth = 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/token/login/'`

#### auth.component.ts

```
interface TokenObj {
  auth_token: string;
}


 authForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl(''),
    password: new FormControl(''),
    rememberMe : new FormControl(''),
  });

  headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });

  loginUser(authData) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(authData);
    return this.httpClient.post(this.ApiService.baseUrlAuth, body, {
      headers: this.headers
    },);
  }

  saveForm() {
    this.loginUser(this.authForm.value).subscribe(
      (result: TokenObj) => {
      if (this.authForm.value.rememberMe == true) {
        this.cookieService.set('userToken', result.auth_token)
      }
      sessionStorage.setItem('userSession', result.auth_token);
      window.location.href = '/home';}
      );
  }
```

#### auth.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-6 mx-auto my-auto">
            <form [formGroup]="authForm" (ngSubmit)="saveForm()">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" required
                        formControlName="username">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone
                        else.</small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                        formControlName="password" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" class="form-check-input">
                    <label for="rememberMe" class="form-check-label">Remember Me</label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 250px;">Login</button>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center sign-up">
                    <p>Not a Member</p>
                    <a href="">Sign Up Now</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the `subscribe` there is another method after `next()` which catches the error

Comment: can i find here [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/observables)?

Comment: You can refer this https://angular.io/guide/observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `error()` method in the `subscribe()`

app.component

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {
    testService.fakeCall().subscribe(
      (data) => { // next() method block
        console.log("Log from next() method");
        console.log(data)
      },
      (error) => { // error() method block
        console.log("Log from error() method");
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

test.service

```
export class TestService {

  fakeCall() {
    return throwError("There is some error occurred...");
  }
}
```

You can check working example from this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r7jbvx)

I suggest you to refer [HTTP interceptors in angular](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor#description)